# PHP: links for URL preg_replace after %

Tags: php, regex

I have this expression:

```
$content = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $content);
```

But a link like

```
http://photoartkalmar.com/Photoart%20Kalmar%20high%20res/Gigapixel/Vienna%2050%20Gigapixel/Donauturm.html
```

or that ends with `something.jpg`

The anchor link stops at % or . on the urls, so it doesnt make it all a link only half of it. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, put a `%` symbol in the correct place in the regex: `[\w/_\.]` → `[\w/_\.%]`

Look at this whole line to see exactly where:

```
$content = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.%]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $content);
```